# Copying data from one workbook to another using relative references

Tags: vba, excel

I have a large workbook with data and I need to copy data from specific columns from a predetermined number of rows into another workbook. The data will always come from the same columns, but the relevant rows will be different each day.

For example, my workbook has 1000 rows and 15 columns, and today I need to copy the content of the cells in columns A, K, & J from row 100 into cells B3, B2, & B1, respectively, then the data from columns A, K, & J from row 101 into cells C3, C2, & C1, in the new workbook. Here's what I have so far:

```
Dim WB1 As Workbook
Dim WS1 As Worksheet
Dim SelectWB As Variant
Dim FilePath As Variant
Dim WB2 As Workbook
Dim Quantity As Integer
Dim x As Integer
Dim ColumnRef As Integer

Application.ReferenceStyle = xlR1C1

Set WB1 = ActiveWorkbook
Set WS1 = ActiveSheet
Quantity = InputBox("Input the number of rows to be copied")
Set SelectWB = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    With SelectWB
        .ButtonName = "Select"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .Title = "Choose File"
        .InitialView = msoFileDialogViewDetails
        If .Show Then FilePath = .SelectedItems(1)
    End With

Set WB2 = Workbooks.Open(FilePath)

ColumnRef = 2

For x = 1 To TagQuantity
    If x <= TagQuantity Then
        Selection.Copy
        WB2.Sheets(3).Cells(3, ColumnRef).Select
        Sheets(3).Paste
        WB1.WS1.ActiveCell.Offset(0, 10).Select
        'Selection.Copy
        'WB2.ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Paste
        'WB1.WS1.ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Copy
        'WB2.ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Paste
        'WB1.WS1.ActiveCell.Offset(1, -9).Select
        'ColumnRef = ColumnRef + 1
    End If
Next

Application.ReferenceStyle = xlA1

End Sub
```

My code error out at the line "WB1.WS1.ActiveCell.Offset(0, 10).Select" (Run-time error '438': Object doesn't support this property or method). If I comment out the error line and run just the first 3 lines in the if statement, it doesn't crash, but also doesn't copy the value into the new sheet. What am I doing wrong?

I am very new to programming, so any help is appreciated!

Comment: That is because at that point it no longer is the activecell.  The best would be to `WB1.WS1.Range()`  but you will need to know the range address.

Answer (score 0):

try adding this in:

```
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = ActiveCell
Application.GoTo rng
```

Here it is added into the code you provided:

```
Dim WB1 As Workbook
Dim WS1 As Worksheet
Dim rng as Range
Dim SelectWB As Variant
Dim FilePath As Variant
Dim WB2 As Workbook
Dim Quantity As Integer
Dim x As Integer
Dim ColumnRef As Integer

Application.ReferenceStyle = xlR1C1

Set WB1 = ActiveWorkbook
Set WS1 = ActiveSheet
Set rng = ActiveCell
Quantity = InputBox("Input the number of rows to be copied")
Set SelectWB = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    With SelectWB
        .ButtonName = "Select"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .Title = "Choose File"
        .InitialView = msoFileDialogViewDetails
        If .Show Then FilePath = .SelectedItems(1)
    End With

Set WB2 = Workbooks.Open(FilePath)

ColumnRef = 2

For x = 1 To TagQuantity
    If x <= TagQuantity Then
        Selection.Copy
        WB2.Sheets(3).Cells(3, ColumnRef).Select
        Sheets(3).Paste
        Application.Goto rng.Offset(0, 10)
        'WB1.WS1.ActiveCell.Offset(0, 10).Select
        'Selection.Copy
        'WB2.ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Paste
        'WB1.WS1.ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Copy
        'WB2.ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Paste
        'WB1.WS1.ActiveCell.Offset(1, -9).Select
        'ColumnRef = ColumnRef + 1
    End If
Next

Application.ReferenceStyle = xlA1

End Sub
```